are ducted fans better than turbines generating vaccum?
Basically I want to make a trap that sucks mosquitoes into a screen container for future studies, to do this I need to generate a vacuum and I need to choose whether to use a ducted fan (simpler) or some type of turbine. Is there any type that would clearly be more efficient in this application? I read a lot about aiflow and static pressure, but I can't understand which is more important in this case

you don't need a vacuum you need air flow.  Unlikely you can generate any meaningful vacuum unless it is an enclosed space.

Centrifugal turbines ("blowers") use less power to create higher pressure.
Axial turbines ("fans"), use less power to create higher flow rates.
Radial turbines ("water wheels") generally work with even higher pressure/lower flow rates.
If you want to catch more mosquitos, you need to catch more air, which means you want a higher flow rate.
If you want to use a very long suction hose, or a very long transmission hose on the outlet, you might consider using a blower, but cheap, low power, low-voltage or battery powered blowers are less common than cheap, low power, low voltage or battery powered fans: you'd probably be better off just getting a more expensive fan, rather than trying to find a cheaper blower.

A ducted fan is in fact the very simplest and most basic example of a turbine. Ducted fans driven directly by electric motors are the cheapest way to set air in motion and are your best bet for this sort of application.
Very handy, cheap, and quiet ducted fans can be salvaged from modular computer power supplies or purchased in a wide variety of sizes and capacities from on-line suppliers like Marlon P. Jones & Associates.

To pull mosquitoes into a screen trap, you might consider an air/steam or water orifice aspirator and avoid rotating machinery and electricity.
